# How to draw half circle at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox

I am working on project where I have requirement to draw half circle to the top left side of the page , I tried very hard but not achieved my goal .I think it might be silly question to ask but trust me I am new to CSS and HTML . Could someone please help me how to achieve this. Code example will be helpful and appreciated .

Thanks.

[image: Sample which I want to acheive]

Comment: Can you provide your current Nav code?

Comment: Do you speak from the circle radius in the navbar or the purple circle on the top left which is cropped?

Comment: @johannchopin Yes , purple circle . I need to draw same like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the navbar's rounded ends, you can accomplish this using [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).

If you're referring to the background circle, you can use a [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient):

```css
html, body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, lavender 49px, transparent 50px);
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left -20px top -30px;
}

h1 {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bookfy</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code for half circle on left top corner.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content= 
        "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  
    <title>Semi Circle</title> 
  
    <style> 
        * { 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; 
            background-color: white; 
  
        } 
        .semi-circle { 
            transform: translate(0, 0); 
            height: 100px; 
            width: 200px; 
            border-radius: 0 0 150px 150px; 
            background-color: #C0C0C0; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <div class="semi-circle"></div> 
</body> 
  
</html>
```

[something more..](https://one7techlab.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily draw this circle in pure css and then position it in the corner with a `position: absolute`:

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-30%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #D8D5F5;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```